# IF Statesment using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to different events depending on what application is currently the `"open"` application - The one which is foremost of the screen. I have managed to save the name of the application using a variable. Using this code.

```
tell application "System Events" 

    item 1 of (get name of processes whose frontmost is true)
    set openWindow to (get name of processes whose frontmost is true)
    do shell script "echo " & openWindow & " > /Users/name/temp/currentWindow.txt"

end tell
```

I then tried to use this code do different events for each open application

```
tell application "System Events"

  if openWindow = "AppleScript Editor" then
    display dialog "my variable: " & openWindow
  end if

end tell
```

However this code does not apper to do anything, I don't have any error messages or anything however the code doesn't display the dialog box. If I place the code for the dialog box in the first section of code it will display the name of the open application.

Any ideas on how to get this to work, it would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain your problem, it's because of this code...

```
set openWindow to (get name of processes whose frontmost is true)
```

That code returns a list of items. Notice you asked for processes (plural), so you can get more than one so applescript gives it to you as a list whether there's one or more items found. What's strange is that in the line above this you do ask for "item 1" of the list but for some reason you don't do anything with that line of code. Normally I would write that line of code like this so I only get item 1...

```
set openWindow to name of first process whose frontmost is true
```

**Anyway, you can't compare the string "AppleScript Editor" to a list {"AppleScript Editor"}. They are not equal so your if statement is never true.**

Display dialog displays a string. So when you move that code outside the if statement, applescript is smart enough to convert your list into a string so it can be displayed.

So bottom line is you are getting a list and you must access the items of the list. The items are strings so get one (in your case you want item 1) and use that in the if statement.

Hopefully you can learn from this explanation. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the first script cast the openWindow variable to a string:

```
set openWindow to (get name of processes whose frontmost is true) as string
```